# How can I add an audio to my SRS if it is missing on Forvo?

Tags: resource-request, self-learning, electronic-resources, listening, spaced-repetition

I like to have an audio file play automatically on my SRS. In fact I found out that most words I have trouble in memorizing lack the audio file, and thus I always add the audio file which I download on Forvo.com.

However, some words lack the audio file on Forvo. This is especially true of idioms, such as *se creuser la cervelle*, or reflexive verb such as *se démener*.

Forvo.com seems not to allow the user to send an audio request to other users, as far as I know.

At first I considered asking a native speaker to give me a recording, but it is rather difficult to meet a native speaker who can help, especially for free. So I rather want to download it somewhere on the Internet.

The audio file should be mp3 file with about 20kb.

In this case how can I get the audio file that is not available in Forvo? If it is too broad and the answer must split by each language, I want to know about French now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forvo.com actually does allow you to submit word requests. If a word is not found, for example, [kakistocratie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/kakistocratie), you get a response that looks as follows:

[image: Error message on Forvo.com]

For readability, here is what this message says: "Wow, you actually found a word not on Forvo!" Below that is a blue button with the words, "Add kakistocratie to know its pronunciation".

If you click that button, you get a form that looks as follows:

[image: Form and instructions for submitting a new word request]

Below the instructions, you can enter a word or phrase and then select the language. I did this a few times for Chinese words and a new pronunciation usually appeared within 24 hours. (Note that you need to be logged in if you want to submit a pronunciation request.)

After the new pronunciation has been added, you can add it to Anki.

Note: Since I actually submitted "kakistocratie", here is a link for another word that is not yet on Forvo at the time of writing (24.05.2019): [kakistocratique (Forvo.com)](https://forvo.com/search/kakistocratique/) or [kakistocratique (fr.forvo.com)](https://fr.forvo.com/search/kakistocratique/).

Comment: Can you get me how you got to the page, with the URL? Since I typed in the word directly, I just got 404 page. For example:  https://fr.forvo.com/word/des_moion/#fr and the search result also doesn't have the button: https://fr.forvo.com/search/des%20moion/

Comment: @Blaszard Instead of your first link, you should have used https://fr.forvo.com/search/des%20moion/ (without the underscore). I have now added links to my answer.

Comment: It seems that the last page of the search result has the button. Do you mean that just adding a word is enough to get the audio, since someone will be notified of the addition and are willing to add the audio?

Comment: French words without a pronunciation are added to a [list](https://forvo.com/pronounce/fr/) (but my submission is not listed yet). On your own account, you can go to "Words" (at the top of the page, between "Account info" and "Messages") to see the words you suggested.